# RaphaelJS/Javascript update path instead of creating new one

Tags: javascript, raphael, updates

I have a textbox where the position of a co-ordinate have to be entered. Then after that by clicking on **Set**, the text(co-ordinates) are assigned to variable *c*. And clicking **Draw** draws a path to the defined co-ordinate.

What I want to do is update the existing path every time I click on **Draw**. But all it does is keep creating new paths when I click on **Draw**. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9KAx/)

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="raphael.js"></script>
<script>
var c, previous1, linepath;
var l = 5;
var x = 1;

window.onload = function(){


    set = function(){
        c = document.getElementById("b1").value;//get the co-ords
        circ();//draw circle at the select co-ord
    }

    var paper = Raphael(0,80,600,600);  


    draw = function(){  
        if (x==1){
            previous1 = "M100,100 L";
            x++;
        }else{
            previous1 = window.linepath + " ";
        }

        var new1 = previous1 + window.c;
        linepath = new1;
        var line = paper.path(linepath);

        var path = paper.text(10,l,linepath);
        path.attr({"text-anchor":"start","font-size":"12"});
        l = l+10;       
    };

    function circ(){
        var posX = c.substring(0,3);
        var posY = c.substring(4,7);
        var circl = paper.circle(posX,posY,5).attr({fill:'red',stroke:'none'});
    };


}
</script>


</head>
<body>
    Enter co-ords  >  Click Set  >  Click Draw
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="b1" value="100,400">
    <button type="button" onclick="set()">Set</button>

    <button type="button" onclick="draw()">Draw</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy: You're making a new Raphael.path() object each time the user clicks "draw," when you need to be updating the existing one (if "draw" has been clicked at least once already).

```
//line needs to be declared outside the function, without an initial value
if (typeof line === "undefined") {
    line = paper.path(linepath);    
} else {
  line.attr("path", linepath);  
}
```

While we're here, you don't want to assume the user enters three-digit values for the coordinates if you're not establishing that condition as a restriction. Instead of getting the x/y values from the input with substrings, do this:

```
var posX = parseInt(c.split(",")[0], 10);
var posY = parseInt(c.split(",")[1], 10);
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9KAx/1/)